# Parse page with Selenium&Python

Tags: python, selenium

I need find button, to take access to mail in my post service in beget.com. I can take list of all buttons , using:

```
buttons = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('operations')
```

code of class "operations":

```
<td class="operations">
  <a title="Открыть почтовый ящик" st="link-mail-settings-open-mail-alex@craftmail.ru" class="btn btn-icon open-mail mail"></a>
  <a href="/mail/alex@craftmail.ru/synchronization" title="Настроить синхронизацию почтового ящика" st="link-mail-settings-go-to-sync-alex@craftmail.ru" class="mail-sync"></a>
  <a title="Удалить почтовый ящик" st="button-mail-settings-delete-alex@craftmail.ru" class="del"></a>
</td>
```

I need to choose button related with mail from my list
Code of button:

```
<a title="Открыть почтовый ящик" st="link-mail-settings-open-mail-alex@craftmail.ru" class="btn btn-icon open-mail mail"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find your button like this:

```
buttons[0].click()
```

0 = number of button you have to click (you can do +1 until you find the button)